# What APi can I use to get the envelops that the user should sign?

Tags: docusignapi

is there any api to get the envelops that the sign in user need to sign or review.
the api that i found only gets the envelops that I create (Envelopes
: listStatusChanges)

Comment: Yes, there is an [API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/) for that. What is the way you create envelopes?

Comment: I send it to the signer via email. 
then the signer receive it.
but if the signer use the lisStatusChanges api, he will not see the envelop.
so how can he see the envelop? how can I retrieve all the envelops that he should sign or review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a GET call to this endpoint

```
restapi/v2.1/accounts/[AccountId]/envelopes?from_date=2021-03-31T06:59:59.000Z&to_date=2021-05-30T06:59:59.000Z&user_id=[UserId]&start_position=0&count=38&order=desc&order_by=last_modified&folder_types=inbox&include=recipients,powerform,folders&include_purge_information=true&query_budget=10
```

Remember to fill the correct **AccountId** and **UserId** you need.
Also note the dates, to from, may need to be modified or dynamically set.